# Jest + Playwright - Test callbacks of event-based DOM library

Tags: javascript, jestjs, dom-events, webautomation, playwright

I have a [library](https://yaireo.github.io/color-picker/) which I wish to test, which is a simple *color picker*.

I want to test the DOM callbacks (which the events-of the library handles internally) are fired.
and was wondering what would be the correct approach to test it.

- Does Playwright has access to the `cPicker` object on the page?
- Does it has access to the `window` object?
- Should I trigger the events from the HTML file itself, and in the callbacks, print in the DOM the result, in some dummy-element, and then infer from that dummy element text that the callbacks fired?

I'm unsure of the range of possibilities in such scenario - 
If anyone knows, please assist, **thank you**.

#### `/tests/visual/basic.html`

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="/dist/color-picker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/styles.css">
<script type="module">
    const cPicker = new ColorPicker({
        onClickOutside(e){
        },
        onInput(color){
        },
        onChange(color){
        }
    })

    document.body.appendChild(cPicker.DOM.scope)
</script>
```

#### Jest Test (with PlayWright)

```js
it('Should call all callbacks with correct arguments', async() => {
    await page.goto(`http://localhost:5000/tests/visual/basic.html`, {waitUntil:'load'})

    // Wait until the next frame
    await page.evaluate(() => new Promise(requestAnimationFrame))

    // TODO: Wtite the test which infers onInput/onChange/onClickOutside callbacks fired
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite close to a "need more focus" question. But let's try to give it some focus:

> Does Playwright has access to the cPicker object on the page?
> Does it has access to the window object?

Yes, you can access both cPicker and the window object inside an evaluate call.

> Should I trigger the events from the HTML file itself, and in the callbacks, print in the DOM the result, in some dummy-element, and then infer from that dummy element text that the callbacks fired?

Exactly, or you can assign values to a javascript variable:

```
const cPicker = new ColorPicker({
  onClickOutside(e){
  },
  onInput(color){
    window['color'] = color;
  },
  onChange(color){
    window['result'] = color;
  }
})
```

And then

```
it('Should call all callbacks with correct arguments', async() => {
    await page.goto(`http://localhost:5000/tests/visual/basic.html`, {waitUntil:'load'})

    // Wait until the next frame
    await page.evaluate(() => new Promise(requestAnimationFrame))

    // Act
   
    // Assert
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => window['color']);
    // Check the value
})
```